# How to count association size with waterline/sails?

Tags: many-to-many, sails.js, one-to-many, waterline, sails-mongo

Using sails 0.10.5/waterline 0.10.15:

I cannot find an answer to a simple question: how to count the elements of an association without using populate() (which would load all data).

Let take a simple many2many relation with via:

```
User:
    attributes: {
        following: {
            collection: 'user',
            via: 'follower',
            dominant: true
        },

        follower: {
            collection: 'user',
            via: 'following'
        }
```

Now I need the size of the collections.
Currently I try

```
User.findById(1).populateAll().exec(function(err, user) {
   // count of followings -> user.following.length;
   // count of followers-> user.follower.length;
}
```

which leads to loading the collections.

- I'm missing a count function at collection level to avoid population/loading of data.
- Is there a possibility to access the (auto generated) join tables to run a count-query directly on the join?

Something like:

```
User.findById(1).count({'followings'}).exec(function(err, followings) {
...}
```

or

```
UserFollowingFollow_FollowFollowing.countByUserFollowingFollowId(1).
    exec(function(err, followings) {
...}
```

Comment: This works for me! http://stackoverflow.com/a/29423551/1896897

Answer (score 3):

Waterline does offer the `count` query method and it can be used like this to solve your problem:

```
User.count().where({follower: followerId})
.exec(function(err, numberOfFollowings) {
  //numberOfFollowings will be the integer that you need
})
```

`followerId` is the id that you are passing to `User.findOne()` in your example.

You can also read the [Waterline documentation](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/master/reference/waterline/models/count.md) about this.

Comment: Did you try this ? It did not work for me!
https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/811#issuecomment-235498438

Comment: @Vunb Sorry for the late reply. I believe that when I posted this answer I tested it and it was working with the sails and waterline versions mentioned in the question.